# Смена ключа активации в Windows 2003

Tags: windows, активация

Есть сервер с ОЕМ лицензией. Диск к нему был утерян. Решили установить сервер 2003 стандарт. Ключ само собой не подходит. Знаю, что под ХП есть программа по замене ключа. Под 2003 не запускается. Подскажите, как заменить ключ? )

Answer (score 1):

```
windows/system32/oobe/msoobe.exe /a
```